# Passing stl::vector iteratator entry into function

Tags: c++, vector

I have these definitions:

```
typedef struct tagDemoEntryAssign
{
    COleDateTime datMeeting;
    CString      strAssignment;
    int          iAssignmentType; // AJT v16.0.9
    int          iStudyPoint;     // AJT v16.0.3
    int          iNextStudyPoint; // AJT v16.0.9
} S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN;

using PublisherAssignments = std::vector<S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN>;

typedef struct tagDemoEntryEx
{
    CString     strName;
    E_GENDER    eGender;
    E_POSITION  ePosition;
    E_APPOINTED eAppointed;
    BOOL        bDemonstrations; // AJT v16.0.3

    PublisherAssignments  vectorItemAssign;       // Sorted array of S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN structures.
    PublisherAssignments  vectorItemAssignFuture; // Sorted array of S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN structures (future on active schedule).
} S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX;

using PublisherMap = std::map<CString, S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX>;
using PublisherMapIter = std::map<CString, S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX>::iterator;
```

I have this map:

```
PublisherMap m_mapPublishers;
```

I am iterating the assignments for a publisher in reverse:

```
for (auto & m_mapPublisher : m_mapPublishers)
{
    for (auto iterAssign = m_mapPublisher.second.vectorItemAssign.rbegin();
        iterAssign != m_mapPublisher.second.vectorItemAssign.rend(); iterAssign++)
    {
        S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN sDemoEntryAssign = *iterAssign;
        bool bValidAssignment = GetMostRecentDateForAssignment(m_eAssignmentContext, sDemoEntryAssign);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Previously I was just using `iterAssign->` to access the structure values but I decided to move the code of the inner `for` loop into a method. The only way I have worked out how to pass the structure `iterAssign` into the method is by copying it first.

Was there another way to pass an vectore iterator entry into a function?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How are your definitions relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could pass the value by reference:

```
S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN &sDemoEntryAssign = *iterAssign;
```

or simply:

```
bool bValidAssignment = GetMostRecentDateForAssignment(m_eAssignmentContext, *iterAssign);
```

Just make sure that your `GetMostRecentDateForAssignment` method excepts its parameter by reference:

```
GetMostRecentDateForAssignment(..., const S_DEMO_ENTRY_ASSIGN &sDemoEntryAssign)
```

*Note*: I made it a `const` reference because it doesn't seem that this method is intended to change the value of `sDemoEntryAssign`.